# Wordpress Menu Bug

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a large site with lots of page, and I have wordpress menu I want to put them pages onto, but it lets me put maybe 30 pages and when I try to add more than that it deactivates from the menu area and it wont add the page I'm trying to add to it.

Anyone ever had this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research online it seems like you need to set this in your PHP.ini file:

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000 
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
```

The information was found here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-custom-menu-items-limit-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you very much your a star, will keep updated once I ask my hosting company to do this.